# How to convert properly Eclipse project to Maven project?

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have created in Eclipse Dynamic Web Project. Then I have selected option 'Convert to Maven Project' from 'Configure' from right-click menu. And now I can see red errors on Java Resources folder in my project. But none subfolder is with red error. In which way can I resolve that problem? I am using Eclipse Juno and m2e plugin.
I have recognized that m2n plugin haven't created src/main/java, src/main/resources and src/main/webapp directories in Java Resources. But the error is still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process in manually. You need to create a pom.xml and [change your folder structure to follow Mavens conventions](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). I would recommend to create a [web project via maven archetypes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-webapp.html) and move your project step-by-step into the new structure.